# How to use `StringJoin` in the given example?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Is there a way to use StringJoin to go from:

{{abc, 0000}, {def, 1111}}

To

{{abc_0000},{def_1111}}

I've been trying to use Map and MapThread with StringJoin but have failed.

Comment: One way I've discovered is by using Transpose[] first, then MapThread[]. If there are any other solutions I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming those are lists of strings

```
Map[StringJoin[#[[1]],"_",#[[2]]]&,{{"abc", "0000"}, {"def", "1111"}}]
```

returns

```
{"abc_0000","def_1111"}
```

Comment: Alternatively, one may use `Apply`:  `Apply[StringJoin[{#1, "_", #2}] &, {{"abc", "0000"}, {"def",  "1111"}}, {1}]`.

Comment: For a points-free (point-less?) solution, you can try `Map[Curry[StringRiffle]["_"] /* List]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher - or the abbreviated form: `StringJoin[{#1, "_", #2}] & @@@
 {{"abc", "0000"}, {"def", "1111"}}`

Answer (score 5):

`StringRiffle` is another solution.

```
Map[StringRiffle[#, "_"] &, {{"abc", "0000"}, {"def", "1111"}}]
```

> {"abc_0000", "def_1111"}

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching also comes in handy:

```
strs = {{"abc", "0000"}, {"def", "1111"}};

Cases[strs, {a_, b_} :> StringJoin[a , "_", b]]
 (* {"abc_0000", "def_1111"} *)

Replace[strs, {a_, b_} :> StringJoin[a , "_", b], {1}]
 (* {"abc_0000", "def_1111"} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"abc", "0000"}, {"def", "1111"}};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
SequenceReplace[list, {{a_, b_}} :> StringJoin[a, "_", b]]
```

{"abc_0000", "def_1111"}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> StringRiffle[x, "_"], All] @ list
```

{"abc_0000", "def_1111"}

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
list /. x :{__String} :> StringRiffle[x, "_"]
```

{"abc_0000", "def_1111"}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{"abc", "0000"}, {"def", "1111"}};
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {{a_, b_}} :> {StringJoin[a, "_", b]}]

(*{{"abc_0000"}, {"def_1111"}}*)
```

A variant with `Cases` and `Insert`:

```
Cases[list, x_ :> {StringJoin@Insert[x, "_", 2]}]

(*{{"abc_0000"}, {"def_1111"}}*)
```

Or using `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[{#1 <> "_" <> #2} &, Thread[list]]

(*{{"abc_0000"}, {"def_1111"}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `ListFormat`:**

```
strs = {{"abc", "0000"}, {"def", "1111"}};

TextString[#, ListFormat -> {"", "_", ""}] & /@ strs
```

**Using `Riffle`:**

```
Riffle[#, "_"] & /@ strs // Map[StringJoin]
```

---

*Result(s):*

> {"abc_0000", "def_1111"}